# Copy input text to another, inside a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, key, getelementbyid

This page generates a table contaning routes, and in the end of every "tr" there is a button that should copy the text inside those 2 fields in each line to the Name3 and Name 4 inputs, respectively.

But when I click, nothing is happening, I think that `getElementById("Name1_".index)` is making the hole code invalid, but how to make it correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function copyTextValue(key) {
                        var index = key;
                        var text1 = document.getElementById("Name1_".index).value;
                        var text2 = document.getElementById("Name2_".index).value;
                        document.getElementById("Name3").value = text1;
                        document.getElementById("Name4").value = text2;
                        }
</script>

         <input type="text" id='Name3' />
         <input type="text" id='Name4' />

        <?php

        $get_rotas = file_get_contents('routes.txt');

        $array = explode("\r\n", $get_rotas);

        foreach($array as $key=>$rota) {

            //Route(rota) Example: TRM J169 BLH V16 BXK|3666

            $rota_distance = explode("|", $rota);

            echo "<tr bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"Name1_$key\" value='" . $rota_distance[0] . "'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"Name2_$key\" value='" . $rota_distance[1] . "'/></td>";

            echo "<td><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"copyTextValue($key);\" value=\"Copy\" ></td>";

            echo "</tr>";

            } 

            ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For concatenating strings in JavaScript use `+` instead of `.`.

Comment: Exactly, I'm a totaly noob on javascript! Thanks!